# If $x+y+z=6$ and $xyz=2$, then find $\cfrac{1}{xy} +\cfrac{1}{yz}+\cfrac{1}{zx}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x+y+z=6$ and $xyz=2$, then find the value of $$\cfrac{1}{xy}
>  +\cfrac{1}{yz}+\cfrac{1}{zx}$$

I've started by simply looking for a form which involves the given known quantities ,so:

$$\cfrac{1}{xy} +\cfrac{1}{yz} +\cfrac{1}{zx}=\cfrac{yz\cdot zx +xy \cdot zx +xy \cdot yz}{(xyz)^2}$$

Now this might look nice since I know the value of the denominator but if I continue to work on the numerator I get looped :

$$\cfrac{yz\cdot zx +xy \cdot zx +xy \cdot yz}{(xyz)^2}=\cfrac{4\left(\cfrac{1}{xy}+\cfrac{1}{zy}+\cfrac{1}{zy}\right)}{(xyz)^2}=\cfrac{4\left(\cfrac{(\cdots)}{(xyz)^2}\right)}{(xyz)^2}$$

How do I deal with such continuous fraction ?

Comment: Is $(xyz)^2$ the lowest common denominator?

Comment: $\frac{1}{xy} +\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}=\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}$.

Comment: lol I've messed up so badly.Shame on me....

Comment: Do I delete the question or leave it (In case someone will do the same mistake (I know that's impossible)) ?

Comment: The least common denominator, with these symbols, is $xyz$. So your expression is $$\tfrac z{xyz}+\tfrac x{xyz} + \tfrac y{xyz}$$It should now be clear how to proceed...

Comment: @Mr.Y Too late. Someone has upvoted an answer, so you can't delete your question anymore.

Comment: Don't automatically think you should delete a question/answer if it is flawed. People can still learn from it. That's the beauty of making mistakes.

Comment: @ user236182 It's fine.

Comment: Thank you guys.It's nice to get some help even when one does the dumbest of the mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\cfrac{1}{xy} +\cfrac{1}{yz} +\cfrac{1}{zx}=\cfrac{yz\cdot zx +xy \cdot zx +xy \cdot yz}{(xyz)^2}=\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}$$

Comment: I don't know if that's a joke.

Comment: don't worry sometime it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the method is straight forward simply take L.C.M. & substitute known values as follows  $$\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}=\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}=\frac{6}{2}=\mathbb{\color{red}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y+z=6$$
Divide both sides with $xyz$
$$\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}=\frac{6}{xyz}$$
$$\frac{x}{xyz}+\frac{y}{xyz}+\frac{z}{xyz}=\frac{6}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}=3$$

Comment: Is your third equation a typo?